# Matlab: Error when working with higher order QAM signal - Matrix dimension must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix, signal-processing, equalizer, modulation

This problem seems to be trivial but I am left scratching my head when trying to resolve it. I am trying to apply Fractionally spaced equalizer with constant modulus technique for 64 QAM constellation. The program works for QPSK or 4 QAM but when I apply it to 64QAM, it throws error :

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Working_FSE_CMA_64QAM (line 68)
sb1=sb/(fh(temp));  % scale the output
```

I don not have the Communications toolbox so have generated 64QAM symbols using the answer given in my previous question [Generate 16 QAM signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403517/generate-16-qam-signal)

Can somebody please help in making the code work? Thank you.

```
% Blind channel estimation/equalization
% adpative CMA method in Fractional space

T=1000;    % total number of data
dB=25;     % SNR in dB value

%%%%%%%%% Simulate the Received noisy Signal  %%%%%%%%%%%
N=5; % smoothing length N+1
Lh=5;  % channel length = Lh+1
Ap=4;  % number of subchannels or receive antennas

h=randn(Ap,Lh+1)+sqrt(-1)*randn(Ap,Lh+1);   % channel (complex)
for i=1:Ap, h(i,:)=h(i,:)/norm(h(i,:));    end        % normalize
s = (randi(8,1,T)*2-5)+j*(randi(8,1,T)*2-5);  %64 QAM
%s=round(rand(1,T))*2-1;  % QPSK or 4 QAM symbol sequence
%s=s+sqrt(-1)*(round(rand(1,T))*2-1);

% generate received noisy signal
x=zeros(Ap,T);    % matrix to store samples from Ap antennas
SNR=zeros(1,Ap);
for i=1:Ap
    x(i,:)=filter(h(i,:),1,s);
    vn=randn(1,T)+sqrt(-1)*randn(1,T);   % AWGN noise (complex)
    vn=vn/norm(vn)*10^(-dB/20)*norm(x(i,:));  % adjust noise power
    SNR(i)=20*log10(norm(x(i,:))/norm(vn));   % Check SNR of the received samples
    x(i,:)=x(i,:)+vn;                        % received signal
end
SNR=SNR    % display and check SNR

%%%%%%%%%%%%% adaptive equalizer estimation via CMA
Lp=T-N;   %% remove several first samples to avoid 0 or negative subscript
X=zeros((N+1)*Ap,Lp);  % sample vectors (each column is a sample vector)
for i=1:Lp
    for j=1:Ap
        X((j-1)*(N+1)+1:j*(N+1),i)=x(j, i+N:-1:i).';
    end
end

e=zeros(1,Lp);  % used to save instant error
f=zeros((N+1)*Ap,1); f(N*Ap/2)=1;    % initial condition
%R2=2;                  % constant modulas of QPSK symbols
R2 = 1.380953; %For 64 QAM http://www.google.com/patents/US7433400
mu=0.001;      % parameter to adjust convergence and steady error
for i=1:Lp
   e(i)=abs(f'*X(:,i))^2-R2;                  % instant error
   f=f-mu*2*e(i)*X(:,i)*X(:,i)'*f;     % update equalizer 
   f(N*Ap/2)=1;
%   i_e=[i/10000 abs(e(i))]             % output information 
end   

%sb=f'*X;   % estimate symbols (perform equalization)
sb = filter(f, 1, X);
% calculate SER
H=zeros((N+1)*Ap,N+Lh+1);  temp=0;
for j=1:Ap
    for i=1:N+1, temp=temp+1; H(temp,i:i+Lh)=h(j,:); end  % channel matrix
end

fh=f'*H;    % composite channel+equalizer response should be delta-like 
temp=find(abs(fh)==max(abs(fh)));   % find the max of the composite response

sb1=sb/(fh(temp));  % scale the output
sb1=sign(real(sb1))+sqrt(-1)*sign(imag(sb1));  % perform symbol detection
start=N+1-temp;  % general expression for the beginning matching point
sb2=sb1(10:length(sb1))-s(start+10:start+length(sb1));  % find error symbols
SER=length(find(sb2~=0))/length(sb2)   % calculate SER

if 1
    subplot(221), 
    plot(s,'o');   % show the pattern of transmitted symbols
    grid,title('Transmitted symbols');  xlabel('Real'),ylabel('Image')
    axis([-2 2 -2 2])

    subplot(222),
    plot(x,'o');  % show the pattern of received samples
    grid, title('Received samples');  xlabel('Real'), ylabel('Image')

    subplot(223),
    plot(sb,'o');   % show the pattern of the equalized symbols
    grid, title('Equalized symbols'), xlabel('Real'), ylabel('Image')

    subplot(224),
    plot(abs(e));   % show the convergence
    grid, title('Convergence'), xlabel('n'), ylabel('Error e(n)')
end
```

Comment: what is the dimension of `temp` while doing `fh(temp)`? My guess is it would be greater than one.

Comment: For the case of 4 QAM or QPSK, temp is a scalar having value = 9. For 64 QAM, temp is empty. This is what baffles me and do not know what to do. Am I generating 64 QAM correctly? Do I need to use the statement : s = (randi(8,1,T)*2-5)+j*(randi(8,1,T)*2-5);  and s=s+sqrt(-1)*(round(rand(1,T))*2-1);

Comment: Another major unjustified edit. Please let me know the reason you have made these edits, or if you wish to roll them back, in case I think it is appropriate to involve a moderator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the iterative algorithm does not converge (or more specifically diverges). As a results the values in `f` contains `NaN`. The result of

```
temp=find(abs(fh)==max(abs(fh)))
```

is then an empty vector which thus does not match the expected scalar size on the line

```
sb1=sb/(fh(temp));  % scale the output
```

To fix the problem, you may note that the value of `mu` and `R2` you use are based on a signal constellation with unit variance. You can generate such a 64-QAM constellation with:

```
s = ((randi(8,1,T)*2-9)+j*(randi(8,1,T)*2-9))/sqrt(42);  %64 QAM
```

Also, a few lines redefine the complex constant `j=sqrt(-1)` to use as an index variable. You should avoid using `j` as index. Also, clearing all variables at the beginning of your sript (with `clear all`) can help start you execution with a consistent clean state.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it is not clear why you are dividing by sqrt of 42? Why the number 42?Another thing, I am still getting the same error when I applied the statement given by you and temp variable is empty.

Comment: I had forgotten that the norm factor is 42. So, that is now clear. However, still the problem persists. Please help so that the code can work.

Comment: Hi, the code still throws error and the symbol error rate calculation also does not work after I did changes based on your suggestions

Comment: The line sb2=sb1(10:length(sb1))-s(start+10:start+length(sb1));  is also creating trouble

Comment: `fh` is a vector of size `N+Lh+1` (hence `1<=temp<=N+Lh+1`). Your computation `start=N+1-temp` could thus yield a negative offset (and out-of-bound indexing into `s` for `Lh>=10`). For the symbol error there are a number of issues including the lack of phase recovery and a symbol detection scheme based on threshold detection suitable for 4-QAM (instead of choosing the closest symbol), but that's beyond the original question.

Comment: Can you please provide the correct implementation since the answer that you gave does not work when I fixed the constellation

Comment: Changing the script with the updated constellation and include `clear all` at the top should no longer produce the error quoted. The symbol error rate is an entirely different question (and perhaps better suited for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).